# OutputCache an ActionResult that only returns a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

Would it make sense to [OutputCache] something like this?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult About()
{
    return this.View("About");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what is in the View. For example if it a heavier view and the output is same for all the users then yes you should use the `[OutputCache]` filter. This will reduce the timing on the server side for:

- View relocation
- View parsing

When you use the `[OutputCache]` filter consider setting the parameters properly. i.e. cache duration and others as needed.

Comment: The view is not heavy. But I've seen in other's code that even on these, they've put OutputCache, I was wondering if there's any benefit from this, my gut instinct tells me it is not.

Comment: @CătălinRădoi I have explained what would be a good/bad scenario to use that.